# grep output different in bash script

Tags: bash, command-line-arguments

I am creating a bash script that will simply use grep to look through a bunch of logs for a certain string.

Something interesting happens though.

For the purpose of testing all of the log files the files are named test1.log, test2.log, test3.log, etc.

When using the grep command:

```
grep -oHnR TEST Logs/test*
```

The output contains all instances from all files in the folder as expected.

But when using a command but contained in the bash script below:

```
#!/bin/bash
#start

grep -oHnR $1 $2

#end
```

The output displays the instances from only 1 file.

When running the script I am using the following command:

```
bash test.bash TEST Logs/test*
```

Here is an example of the expected output (what occurs when simply using grep):

```
Logs/test2.log:8:TEST    
Logs/test2.log:20:TEST    
Logs/test2.log:41:TEST    
Logs/test.log:2:TEST    
Logs/test.log:18:TEST
```

and here is an example of the output received when using the bash script:

```
Logs/test2.log:8:TEST    
Logs/test2.log:20:TEST    
Logs/test2.log:41:TEST
```

Can someone explain to me why this happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call the line

```
bash test.bash TEST Logs/test*
```

this will be translated by the shell to

```
bash test.bash TEST Logs/test1.log Logs/test2.log Logs/test3.log Logs/test4.log
```

(if you have four log files).

The command line parameters `TEST`, `Logs/test1.log`, `Logs/test2.log`, etc. will be given the names `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, etc.; `$1` will be `TEST`, `$2` will be `Logs/test1.log`.

You just ignore the remaining parameters and use just one log file when you use `$2` only.

A correct version would be this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#start

grep -oHnR "$@"

#end
```

This will pass all the parameters properly and also take care of nastinesses like spaces in file names (your version would have had trouble with these).

Comment: Wow! My idea of how parameters worked in bash were completely wrong. This makes so much sense. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 2):

To understand what's happening, you can use a simpler script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $1
echo $2
```

That outputs the *first two* arguments, as you asked for.

You want to use the first argument, and then use all the rest as input files.  So use `shift` like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
search=$1
shift

echo "$1"
echo "$@"
```

Notice also the use of double quotes.

In your case, because you want the search string and the filenames to be passed to `grep` in the same order, you don't even need to `shift`:

```
#!/bin/bash

grep -oHnR -e "$@"
```

(I added the `-e` in case the search string begins with `-`)

Comment: ⁺¹ for mentioning `-e` :)

Answer (score 1):

The unquoted `*` is being affected by [globbing](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html) when you are calling the script.

Using `set -x` to output what is running from the script makes this more clear.

```
$ ./greptest.sh TEST test*
++ grep -oHnR TEST test1.log
$ ./greptest.sh TEST "test*"
++ grep -oHnR TEST test1.log test2.log test3.log
```

In the first case, bash is expanding the * into the list of file names versus the second case it is being passed to grep. In the first case you actually have >2 args (as each filename expanded would become an arg) - adding `echo $#` to the script shows this too:

```
$ ./greptest.sh TEST test*
++ grep -oHnR TEST test1.log
++ echo 4
4
$ ./greptest.sh TEST "test*"
++ grep -oHnR TEST test1.log test2.log test3.log
++ echo 2
2
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to escape the wildcard on your bash invocation:

```
bash test.bash TEST Logs/test\*
```

That way it'll get passed through to grep as an `*`, otherwise the shell will have expanded it to every file in the Logs dir whose name starts with `test`.

Alternatively, change your script to allow more than one file on the command line:

```
#!/bin/bash
hold=$1
shift
grep -oHnR $hold $@
```